# Passen wir Fragen der akzeptierten Antwort an?

Tags: discussion

[Diese Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/38518/datenbank-mit-mundart-dialekt-in-%C3%96sterreich) hat nach relativ kurzer Zeit eine durchaus gute und dann auch schnell akzeptierte Antwort bekommen - Allerdings deckt die Antwort leider nur den Teilbereich der österreichischen Dialekte ab, obwohl ursprünglich generell nach deutschen Dialekten gefragt wurde.

Dies führte dazu, dass die Frage nachträglich (nicht vom OP) so modifiziert wurde, dass sie spezifisch nach den österreichischen Dialekten fragt, damit die akzeptierte Antwort richtig passt.

Ist das im Sinne der Regeln von GSE? Sollen wir das so machen?

Ich finde das nicht besonders verwerflich, fand es allerdings ein bißchen verwunderlich. Ich dachte, hier sollten die Fragen so beantwortet werden, wie sie gestellt wurden (auch wenn das durchaus etwas länger dauern kann).

Answer (score 9):

Ich habe die Antwort mit dem starken Österreich-Bezug geschrieben, weil ich mein Wissen als Antwort zur gestellten Frage einbringen wollte. Ich bin der Meinung, das eine Teil-Antwort besser als gar keine Antwort ist.

Mir ist klar, dass damit die Frage nicht vollständig beantwortet ist, aber andere Autoren hätten ja die Möglichkeit gehabt, mit eigenen Antworten die von mir offen gelassenen Lücken zu schließen.

Diese Möglichkeit wurde ihnen nun durch Anpassung der Frage an meine Teil-Antwort genommen, und der Autor der Frage wird sich sicherlich darüber wundern (und vermutlich auch ärgern) was andere aus seiner Frage gemacht haben.

Daher sehe ich die nachträgliche Anpassung der Frage an die Antwort als einen Eingriff an, der der Intention des ursprünglichen Verfassers zuwiderläuft. Ich persönlich heiße das nicht gut.

Eine Community-Wiki-Antwort sehe ich auch nicht unbedingt notwendig. Der Fragesteller hat ja nicht nach einer Liste gefragt, sondern nach einer *zentralen Sammelstelle*.

Es ist ja auch durchaus erlaubt und sogar erwünscht, dass auf eine Frage von verschiedenen Autoren mehrere Antworten geschrieben werden, die einander ergänzen und gemeinsam die gestellte Frage beantworten. Warum sonst sollte in der [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/18413/german-language) die durchschnittliche Anzahl von Antworten pro Frage als Qualitätsmaß gemessen werden?

Answer (score 2):

Stack Exchange gibt [gewisse Empfehlungen](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit), nach denen Fragen und Antworten von der Community oder den Moderatoren verbessert werden sollen:

> *Edits are expected to be substantial and to leave the post better than you found it.*
>   Es wird eine wesentliche Bearbeitung erwartet, die einen Beitrag besser macht.

Im genannten Beispiel wurde nach Wörterbüchern für deutsche Dialekte gefragt. Es ist klar, dass man hier nicht eine richtige oder beste Antwort geben kann. Die Frage ist also von vornherein nicht so gut für das StackExchange-Format geeignet. Solche *list questions* sind entweder *off topic*, oder sollten als Community Wiki markiert werden:

- [List questions: Community Wiki?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98334/list-questions-community-wiki)
- [What about a multi-answer question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9782/what-about-a-multi-answer-question)

In der Frage, was nun besser für diese spezielle Frage & Antwort wäre, ein Eingrenzen der Frage auf Österreich, oder Markierung als *Community Wiki* habe ich mich **in diesem konkreten Fall** für Ersteres entschieden. Die Frage passt dann viel besser zur akzeptierten Antwort und damit auch zum Frage-Antwort-Format dieser Seite.

Daraus kann man zwar keine Regel ableiten, wir sollten aber schon den Mut haben, sowohl Fragen als auch Antworten zu bearbeiten, wenn dadurch ein Frage-und-Antwort-Beitrag insgesamt besser wird, denn davon profitiert letztlich unsere Seite.

Answer (score -1):

Fazit vorweg: Das muss in der Theorie eigentlich für jede Frage individuell diskutiert werden. Da das natürlich nicht im Rahmen des Möglichen ist, so kann man es vielleicht wie die "Tatsachenentscheidung" im Sport betrachten. Einzige Bedingung ist natürlich, dass die primäre Intention der Frage nicht verändert wird. Wird diese Bedingung verletzt, so sollte (wie in diesem Fall geschehen) eine Diskussion auf Meta geführt werden — und letztlich gegebenenfalls ein Rollback durchgeführt werden.

In diesem Fall empfinde ich die Änderung als falsch und würde ein Rollback in Betracht ziehen. Hingegen verstehe ich auch die Begründung, dass die Frage sonst am Rande von off-topic ist. Leider beziehen sich auch noch beide Antworten auf Österreich allein. Viel Auswahl ist das nicht. Aber ich möchte doch stark bezweifeln, dass die eigentlich Intention war, die Frage auf einen konkreten Dialekt zu beschränken — insbesondere Österreich. (Ohne an dieser Stelle Österreich abwerten zu wollen; aber wenn die Frage sich auf einen 'ausländischen' Dialekt bzw. auf den Dialekt eines konkreten Landes bezogen hätte, so wäre dies definitiv vom Fragesteller erwähnt worden. Darauf basierend vermute ich, dass die Frage sich rein auf Dialekte innerhalb Deutschlands bezieht.)

Bezüglich der generischen Fragestellung, ob wir Fragen anpassen sollten: Grundsätzlich ja, wenn sich die Frage dadurch wirklich verbessert oder vervollständigt wird.
Beispielsweise ist es vollkommen normal, dass der Fragesteller einige Aspekte in die Frage nicht mit einbringt, weil sie ihm nicht bewusst sind. In einer Antwort werden diese Aspekte hingegen erwähnt. So ist sinnvoll, die Frage entsprechend zu ergänzen.
Ein schlichtes Beispiel: Gängige Frage ist "Was ist der Unterschied zwischen A und B?". Was dem Fragesteller nicht bewusst ist, dass es noch ein Wort "C" gibt, dass im Sinne der Frage hohe Relevanz hat. Hier empfinde ich es als äußerst sinnvoll, das Wort "C" in die Frage aufzunehmen, wenn eine Antwort das Wort aufgreift.

Nun ergibt sich aber ein Problem: Wo genau zieht man die Grenze, also wann ist das Wort "C" wirklich relevant? Es gibt ja immer noch die Synonyme D, E, F, ... Welches dieser Wörter ist noch relevant, welche sind schon zu entfernt?
Dies möchte ich an dieser Stelle natürlich nicht ausdiskutieren und es ist auch nur als ein einfaches Beispiel gedacht und es gibt hunderte anderer Frage, die nicht der Art "Unterschied zw. A und B" sind, und trotzdem überarbeitet werden müssten.

Und somit sind wir letztlich wieder bei der "Tatsachenentscheidung".

Comment: Der OP hatte die Österreich-only als richtige Antwort akzeptiert, sonst wäre ich niemals auf die Idee gekommen irgendetwas an der Frage zu ändern.

Comment: @Takkat Das reicht mir nicht. Antworten wurden schon oft genug akzeptiert, ohne dass die auch nur annährend vollständig waren. Wenn OP bspw. aus der Antwort schlussfolgerte, dass es keinen anderen Datenbanken gibt, so akzeptiert er die Antwort. (Das kann man ja durchaus als Take-Away mitnehmen.) Heißt aber nicht, dass er wirklich nach einer Österreich-Datenbank suchte. Wie gesagt, dann hätte er auch explizit danach gefragt. Und nicht zuletzt ist die Antwort sehr lang und ausführlich. Manch einer lässt sich auch dadurch zum "Akzeptieren" verleiten.

Comment: Diese Art des "Akzeptierens" ist letztlich aber nicht gut für die Seite. Wir müssen immer auch sehen, was passiert, wenn jemand das nach 1 Jahr oder später liest. Wenn er dann auf eine perfekt abgestimmt Q&A stößt ist das super, wenn es dann nur Halbantworten gibt eher traurig.

Comment: Na dann, viel Spaß mit den anderen 28.000 Fragen, die nur Halbantworten haben...

Comment: Das sind keine *list-questions*.